# how to hide the right status in tmux

Tags: tmux

How do I hide the right status in tmux? It appears in the bottom bar where windows appear, all the way right justified.

I have tried `set-option status-right ""` and `set-option status-right-length 0` in ~/.tmux.conf

Answer (score 3):

Setting the global option in `.tmux.conf` is fine indeed:

```
set-option -g status-right ""
```

However, instead of killing and restarting the tmux server and essentially loosing all open sessions, one can simply source the `.tmux.conf` file like so:

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

while in a tmux session, and the settings would be applied to all open sessions instantly !

Answer (score 1):

Set it as a global session option in your `.tmux.conf` using the `-g` flag:

```
set-option -g status-right ""
```

Then reload tmux using:

```
tmux kill-server
tmux
```